# Bootstrap multiple select with ng-model in Angular not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my angular app, I have a bootstrap multiple select. When i do not give an ng-model attribute, it works as expected.

```
<select name="sample" class="form-control" multiple>
     <option 
            ng-repeat="item in vm.items" 
            value="{{item.id}}" 
            selected>
            {{item.name}} 
     </option>
</select>
```

This selects all the available options.

But I provide an ng-model, only the last value gets selected.

```
<select name="sample" class="form-control" multiple ng-model="someModel">
     <option 
            ng-repeat="item in vm.items" 
            value="{{item.id}}" 
            selected>
            {{item.name}} 
     </option>
</select>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: And what is the value of the model someModel?

Comment: Empty as in empty object {} ? or not assigned/undefined

Comment: Use **ng-options** instead of ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not manually render options with ngRepeat. Use ngOptions directive for this:

```
<select name="sample" class="form-control" multiple 
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.items"
    ng-model="vm.someModel">
</select>
```

Now, in order to make all options selected you need to populate `vm.someModel` with corresponding ids. So in controller you could do:

```
this.someModel = this.items.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.items = [{name:'One', id:1}, {name: 'Two', id: 2}, {name: 'Three', id:3}];
    this.someModel = this.items.map(function(item) {
        return item.id;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>


<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <select name="sample" class="form-control" multiple 
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.items"
        ng-model="vm.someModel">
    </select>   
    
    {{ vm.someModel }} 
</div>
```